# Installing VLC media player in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Dear fellow community Members,

I have tried to install VLC media player using various methods prescribed in the question answer tag. However, I am getting the following response :

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
```

will you be able to guide me?

Comment: " various methods" what methods? Did you run apt-get update before running apt-get install?

Comment: Yes xangua 6 $ sudo apt-get update

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: Please remove any third party repository you added and paste the whole output of: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This will install the latest version

---

UPDATE

first enable the Universe

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

then try this

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/stable-daily 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

If ppa-purge is not installed you can install using

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Or use the command `add-apt-repository -r` instead

Comment: Maythux, that I have already done!

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: He did not ask to install the "latest" version, he asked to just install VLC.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install vlc Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package vlc

Comment: try this `sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/stable-daily ` then `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: enable universe if not yet `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"`

Comment: sudo: ppa-purge: command not found

Comment: use this `add-apt-repository -r` instead

Comment: sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo: ppa-purge: command not found
amit@amit-Inspiron-1525:~$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ppa-purge

Comment: make a `sudo apt-get update` before and tell me the output

Comment: The problem was in the software center where wrong server was selected. The OS is now updating.

Comment: ok good to be solved

Answer (score 0):

1) Choose an [up-to-date server](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) in your neighborhood and select it by running software & updates and choosing software sources:

[image: choose server]

2) Enable the Universe repository here:

[image: software and updates]

3) Run software updater

[image: software updater]

4) Install via software center:

[image: vlc-install]